# Exception Handling with Multiple catch block

Tags: java, exception

Here is my program.

```
try {
    int a = 1/0;
}
catch(Exception e) {
    system.out.println("Exception block"+e);
}
catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    system.out.println("Inside ArithmeticException block");
}
finally {
    system.out.println("Inside Finally block");
}
```

In the above program i have two catch blocks and one finally block.

Which catch block will execute? Because I define the parent catch block first. So it leads to an error? Can any one help me?

I assumed that "ArithmeticException and Finally block will be executed"

Comment: Your Exception catch block and finally block will execute

Comment: Has there been any update in newer Java version? I am getting following error while compiling: exception ArithmeticException has already been caught

Answer (score 2):

Catching `Exception` class will not give any error. However, it is not recommended.

In this case, `Exception` `catch` block will execute first and then `finally` block will execute.

If you want that your `ArithmeticException` block should execute, put this block before `Exception` `catch` block.

Update code -

```
    try{
        int a = 1/0;
    }        
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Inside ArithmeticException block");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception block"+e);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Inside Finally block");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching Exception class will not give any error.

In this case, Exception catch block will execute first and then finally block will execute.

If you want that your ArithmeticException block should execute, put this block before Exception catch block.

Here is Updated code

```
 try {
    int a = 1/0;
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception block"+e);
}
finally {
    System.out.println("Inside Finally block");
}
}
```